# Group elastic net

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, feature-selection, lasso, elastic-net

The lasso and the elastic net are not able to handle variables with more than two categories and therefore a split of categorical variables into dummies is necessary for the application of these methods. This can result in [several problems](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273154/is-feature-selection-with-dummy-coding-of-categorical-variables-problematic) and therefore there exist extensions for the lasso to the [group lasso](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~myuan/papers/glasso.final.pdf) or the [sparse group lasso](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/SGLpaper.pdf).

However, I am wondering if such extensions also exist for elastic net. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any statistical literature about the topic.

**Question: Does a group elastic net exist?**

Comment: Look at R's glmnet package ...

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @ kjetil b halvorsen! Are you talking about the option `type.multinomial` in the `glmnet` function? It says: `If "grouped" then a grouped lasso penalty is used on the multinomial coefficients for a variable. This ensures they are all in or out together. The default is "ungrouped"`. If I understand this correctly, then I would just have to perform a regular elastic net with the `glmnet` function, but with `type.multinomial = "grouped"`. Is this correct? Some further elaboration is highly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct.

Comment: In a very real sense, this "group elastic net" is just a version of "group lasso" where the groups are allowed to overlap. For instance, if $\mathcal{G}$ is your set of groups, then run group lasso on $\mathcal{G} \cup \{ \{1, \dots, p\} \}$, where we consider there to be $p$ features. This will be equivalent to the group elastic net up to a reparameterization of the tuning parameter controlling $\{1, \dots, p\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ Ben! Could you please elaborate a bit, what you meant with "allowed to overlap" and "up to a reparameterization of the tuning parameter controlling {1,…,p}." Unfortunately, I am not entirely understanding what you said.

Comment: The set $\mathcal{G} \cup \{\{1, \dots, p\}\}$ is no longer a partition, unlike $\mathcal{G}$ itself. (This is the overlapping comment.) The part about the different parameterization just relates to the objective function I discuss being a reparameterization of the one that you likely are discussing. This comment can largely be ignored imo. Also, the procedure @kjetilbhalvorsen recommends does not appear to be correct. The grouping discussed there is for when there's a multivariate response. That's different. However, you can, for instance, use the `gglasso` package to do this.

Comment: (Note: Don't put a space after the "@", otherwise the user does not get notified.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the grouping that you're interested in; that is, let $\mathcal{G}$ be a partition of $\{1, \dots, p\}$, where we consider there to be $p$ features. With response $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and design matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, the group lasso estimator is $$\arg\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p} \frac{1}{2n} \|y - X \beta \|_2^2 + \lambda \sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} |\mathcal{G}|^{1/2} \|\beta_g\|_2.$$ Applying another squared $\ell_2$ penalty to induce overall shrinkage, we'd get the estimator $$\arg\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p} \frac{1}{2n} \|y - X \beta \|_2^2 + \lambda \sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} |\mathcal{G}|^{1/2} \|\beta_g\|_2 + \mu \|\beta\|_2^2.$$ We might call this the "group elastic net". By Lagrangian duality, we can write 
\begin{align*}
 \arg\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p} & \frac{1}{2n} \|y - X \beta \|_2^2 + \lambda \sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} |\mathcal{G}|^{1/2} \|\beta_g\|_2 + \mu \|\beta\|_2^2 \\
 = \, \arg\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p \, : \, \|\beta\|_2^2 \leq C} & \frac{1}{2n} \|y - X \beta \|_2^2 + \lambda \sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} |\mathcal{G}|^{1/2} \|\beta_g\|_2 \\
 = \, \arg\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p \, : \, \|\beta\|_2 \leq \sqrt{C}} & \frac{1}{2n} \|y - X \beta \|_2^2 + \lambda \sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} |\mathcal{G}|^{1/2} \|\beta_g\|_2 \\
 = \, \arg\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p} & \frac{1}{2n} \|y - X \beta \|_2^2 + \lambda \sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} |\mathcal{G}|^{1/2} \|\beta_g\|_2 + \tilde\mu \|\beta\|_2 \\
 = \, \arg\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p} & \frac{1}{2n} \|y - X \beta \|_2^2 + \left( \lambda \sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} |\mathcal{G}|^{1/2} \|\beta_g\|_2 + \tilde\mu' p^{1/2} \|\beta\|_2 \right),
\end{align*}
where $\tilde\mu$ is the corresponding dual variable and $\tilde\mu' = p^{-1/2} \tilde\mu$. As we can see, this last expression is a group lasso with "overlapping" groups, since $\mathcal{G} \cup \{1, \dots, p\}$ is no longer a partition. Further, the group $\{1, \dots, p\}$ has a dual variable (or tuning variable) $\tilde\mu$ which is distinct from the dual variable $\lambda$ for the other groups.

This can be optimization problem can be solved using the package `gglasso`. Reading the section on page 9 of the documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gglasso/gglasso.pdf) will tell you about the `gglasso` function, which should be used. Note that the argument `pmax` will have to manually supplied with a last component which will serve as a tuning parameter.