# Exclude entire categorical variable? Or just some of its dummies?

Tags: categorical-data, feature-selection, categorical-encoding

I'm trying to predict whether a person is likely to get robbed or not
   (=dependent variable).

- I will use logistic regression (classifier) to make the prediction.
- In my data I have a lot of independent variables: some are numerical, some are categorical.
- I have to convert my categorical variables into dummies. E.g. Ethnicity (latino, asian, etc.) will be converted to is_latino, is_asian, etc. where the values can be either 0 (yes) or 1 (no).
- Since I have a lot of independent variables I want to apply feature selection as I expect that not all of them are actually adding value to the prediction. For now I'm just looking at p-values to start off with (will implement cross-validation at a later stage)

The problem:

- My results show that some dummies are significant, whereas other dummies relating to the same variable are not. E.g. is_latino seems to be very significant, whereas is_asian is not significant.

The question:

- Can I continue by using only those dummies which appear to be significant (is_latino)? Or do I need to keep all the ones which relate to the same variable (ethnicity)?

Comment: The question is asked & answered before on this site:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273154/is-feature-selection-with-dummy-coding-of-categorical-variables-problematic

Comment: Coding 0 for yes and 1 or no is a convention, but one likely to be confusing to yourself and others. It's simpler by far to use the other way round, 1 for yes and 0 if no. (Indeed, it is possible that you really did this and just wrote you did by accident.)

Answer (score 2):

As you already suggest in your question, when you include a categorical variable such as `ethnicity` and decide to model it through `k-1` dummies (assuming you have an `intercept` in the model), you should keep either all of them or none of them.

In essence I think you're interested in whether `ethnicity` has an important / significant effect on your outcome (`being robbed`). If you would remove a certain level of `ethnicity`, then the interpretation changes with it. It could for example be that once you remove `is_latino` that a highly significant level, e.g. `is_asian` would become insignificant.